# Read config file from AppHost with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've implemented an AppHost where I want to connect to Redis but I need to read the server address from a configuration file. How can I do this inside AppHost?

I'm deploying on IIS.

```
  public class AppHost : AppHostBase
  {
     public override void Configure(Container container)
     {
         container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379"));
            container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
     }
  }
```

How can I use the same configuration inside Services implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ServiceStack you would commonly use `AppSettings` to read from the `<appSettings/>` in your Web.config file, e.g:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();

container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
    new PooledRedisClientManager(appSettings.GetString("redis-host")));
```

There is also `ConfigUtils` class if you want to read other parts of the App config file like Connection strings.

Comment: Do you know how to read virtual paths like Sharepoint "_layouts" folder? Something similar with HttpServerUtility.MapPath

Comment: Not sure about Sharepoint, but you can try `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` and `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath` to get details about your hosted environment.